# Getting incorrect date format after converting

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm getting this date from API in string format: "2020-01-02T00:00:00".

Now I wanted to convert this date into `Date` format. So this is what I did for that...

```
var utcTime = "\(dic["Due_Date"]!)" //Printing `utcTime` gives "2020-01-02T00:00:00"
self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
self.dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:utcTime) {
  self.scheduledDate = date //HERE I GET THE DATE AS 2020-01-01 18:30:00 UTC
}
```

The date received in string format is "2020-01-02T00:00:00". But when I convert it to `Date` format, I get the date as `2020-01-01 18:30:00 UTC` which is incorrect.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: If your time zone is UTC+05:30 the date is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set Time Zone to UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)

```
var utcTime = "2020-01-02T00:00:00" //Printing `utcTime` gives "2020-01-02T00:00:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:utcTime) {
  print(date)  //HERE I GET THE DATE AS 2020-01-01 18:30:00 UTC
}
```

Output :- 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You also need to set the timezone.

```
let utcTime =  "\(dic["Due_Date"]!)"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let timezone = TimeZone.init(secondsFromGMT: 0)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = timezone!

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:utcTime) {
  print(date) // 2020-01-02 00:00:00 +0000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let inputDate = "2020-01-02T00:00:00"

let dateFmt = DateFormatter()
dateFmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

if let date = dateFmt.date(from: inputDate) {
    //IF YOU NEED TO CHANGE DATE FORMATE
    dateFmt.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    print(dateFmt.string(from: date))
}
```